# (Un-)bind keys for org-agenda in use-package

Tags: org-mode, key-bindings, org-agenda, use-package

I want to unbind some keys in the org agenda display with use-package.  I did the following:

```
 (use-package org
 :ensure t
 :pin gnu
 :config
 (define-key org-agenda-mode-map (kbd "<C-S-right>") nil)
 (define-key org-agenda-mode-map (kbd "<C-S-left>") nil)
 (define-key org-agenda-mode-map (kbd "<C-S-up>") nil)
 (define-key org-agenda-mode-map (kbd "<C-S-down>") nil))
```

However, this does not work.  I get the message `Error (use-package): org/:config: Symbol’s value as variable is void: org-agenda-mode-map`.  So why does this fail and what  is the trick to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce the error. Basically you need to load `org-agenda` for `org-agenda-mode-map` to be available. You can modify your config a few different ways to fix it.

```
 (use-package org
 :ensure t
 :pin gnu
 :config
 (require 'org-agenda)
 (define-key org-agenda-mode-map (kbd "<C-S-right>") nil)
 (define-key org-agenda-mode-map (kbd "<C-S-left>") nil)
 (define-key org-agenda-mode-map (kbd "<C-S-up>") nil)
 (define-key org-agenda-mode-map (kbd "<C-S-down>") nil))
```

The following is another equivalent option.

```
 (use-package org
   :config
   (use-package org-agenda
     :ensure nil
     :bind
     (:map org-agenda-mode-map
      ("<C-S-right>" . nil)
      ("<C-S-left>" . nil)
      ("<C-S-up>" . nil)
      ("<C-S-down>" . nil))))
```

You can also do something like `:after org` and use a separate `use-package org-agenda` block.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the answer by [Swarnendu Biswas](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/72821/5254) I realised, that it is a bit convoluted to have the key-(un-)bindings for the agenda within the `use-package` block.  I now settled with the following solution:

```
(add-hook 'org-agenda-mode-hook
  '(lambda ()
     (define-key org-agenda-mode-map (kbd "<C-S-right>") nil)
     (define-key org-agenda-mode-map (kbd "<C-S-left>") nil)
     (define-key org-agenda-mode-map (kbd "<C-S-up>") nil)
     (define-key org-agenda-mode-map (kbd "<C-S-down>") nil)
     )
)
```